# Tangent as chord in circle.

Tags: geometry

> Two small circles are tangent to each other and the big circle. Their radii are 3, 6, and 9. What is the length of the chord that is tangent to the two small circles?

https://www.geogebra.org/geometry/nkk7ga3d

All the centers lie on the diameter of the large circle but I haven't gotten much farther. How can I solve this synthetically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $CG$ and $EH$ are both perpendicular to $IJ$ (as $IJ$ is tangent to both circles) and, thus, parallel to each other. Assuming $F$ is meant to be the center of the big circle, draw the line from $F$ parallel to $CG$ and $EH$ so it meets $IJ$ at $K$. Then $FK$ is also perpendicular to $IJ$. In addition, note $CG$ has a length of $3$ and $EH$ has a length of $6$, due to being radii of their circles. As the length of $CF$ is $3 + 3 = 6$ and the length of $FE = 3$, the length of $FK$ is $3 + \left(\frac{6}{6 + 3}\right)(6 - 3) = 3 + \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)(3) = 5$. Also, note that $FJ$ and $FI$, being radii of the big circle, each have a length of $9$.

By the Pythagorean Theorem, the lengths of $IK$ and $KJ$ are the same, with this being $\sqrt{9^2 - 5^2} = \sqrt{56} = 2\sqrt{14}$. Thus, the length of $IJ$ is $4\sqrt{14}$.